# Find the longest prefix of a string s that is a substring of the reversal of the string s 

Tags: java, algorithm

Are there any ways to use linear-time algorithm to find the longest prefix of a string s that is a substring of the reversal of the string s?

Comment: There probably is a DP solution for this. But I can't see how it would go in linear time.

Comment: @aioobe. There is a DP solution, but I believe it's O(n^2) (really O(mn) but m=n for this problem)

Answer (score 4):

Apply Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm to search for the given string (S) in the reversed string (T). At each iteration it will find the longest prefix of S that is a suffix of T[1..i]. Then you just need to find the maximum of the lengths of these prefixes.

Comment: @Ritesh KMP is O(n+m) where n is the length of text, m is the length of substring (equal to n in this case).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's an `O(n)` solution with a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).  Suppose `n` is the length of string `s`.

1. Computing `s`<sub>`rev`</sub>, the reversal of string `s`, is `O(n)` (and actually it can be `O(1)`, but it doesn't matter here).
2. A suffix tree for `s`<sub>`rev`</sub> can be built in `O(n)` time.
3. Longest prefix of `s` in `s`<sub>`rev`</sub> can be found in `O(n)` time using the suffix tree.

Comment: Beat me by ten seconds!  Great answer, +1.

Comment: Could you please post a working example so that it can be handy for further reference